# Cloud Storage API requests from GAE - 403 Access not configured

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-api-python-client

My GAE app is trying to manipulate files stored on Google Cloud Storage.

The files are stored in the default bucket for my app. I already managed to read/write files to that bucket using the GCS Python Client Library (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/).

Unfortunately it does not support copy. Instead, I'm trying the JSON API with the API Client Library (https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/documentation/storage/v1/python/latest/storage_v1.objects.html) and service account (https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/google_app_engine#ServiceAccounts)

So far I'm getting an error 403 when requesting the cloud storage url.

Here's the code:

```
credentials = AppAssertionCredentials(scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write')
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http(memcache))
service = discovery.build('storage', 'v1', http=http, developerKey='api_key_generated_from_the_dev_console')
bucket_name = app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name()

# I'm planning to batch multiple requests, although there is just one in this example
batch = BatchHttpRequest()

# process_list_response outputs the exception if any
batch.add(service.objects().list(bucket=bucket_name), callback=process_list_response) 
batch.execute(http=http)
```

Here's the log:

> URL being requested:
>   https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/storage/v1/rest?userIp=x.x.x.x
>
> Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
>
> URL being requested:
>   https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/xxx.appspot.com/o?alt=json
>
> HttpError 403 when requesting
>   https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/xxx-dev.appspot.com/o?alt=json
>   returned "**Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console
>   to activate the API for your project.**"

Here's what I've done in the dev console:

- Google Cloud Storage and Google Cloud Storage JSON API are switched
  to ON.
- I created an API key which I use to build the service (is it necessary since I also use Oauth?)
- Under Permissions, I added a member for my app with the email xxx@appspot.gserviceaccount.com

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting this as an answer as it seems that my edit (we work together) was silently rejected, and a comment is too limited. This is not an answer but that is expanding the question.

Simpler example with a single http request. It seems that the JSON API is simply not working outside the API explorer. The XML/REST API works and returns a list of files in the bucket.

```
credentials = AppAssertionCredentials(scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write')
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http(memcache))

bucket_name = app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name()

# This works (200 with list of files in the content)
request_url = 'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/' + bucket_name
response, content = http.request(request_url, method="GET")

# This doesn't work (403, Access not configured)
request_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/' + bucket_name + '/o?alt=json'
response, content = http.request(request_url, method="GET")

# This doesn't work (403, Access not configured), the key and project id header seem useless.
request_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/' + bucket_name + '/o?alt=json&key=' + API_KEY
response, content = http.request(request_url, method="GET", headers={'x-goog-project-id': PROJECT_ID})
```

Also, looking at the code of AppAssertionCredentials, we can see:

```
  kwargs: optional keyword args, including:
    service_account_id: service account id of the application. If None or
      unspecified, the default service account for the app is used.

self.service_account_id = kwargs.get('service_account_id', None)
```

Passing anything as service_account_id argument results in an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/.../1.37.../backup.py", line 61, in get
    response, content = http.request(request_url, method="GET")
  File "/base/data/home/apps/.../1.377.../oauth2client/util.py", line 132, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/.../1.37.../oauth2client/client.py", line 491, in new_request
    self._refresh(request_orig)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/.../1.37.../oauth2client/appengine.py", line 197, in _refresh
    raise AccessTokenRefreshError(str(e))
AccessTokenRefreshError
```

I have tested to pass the value returned by `app_identity.get_service_account_name()`, that doesn't work. (even though the documentation says it will use *"the default service account for the app"* if it is not set).

I have tested to pass the service account email found in the developer console that has the form: `3....-v0....@developer.gserviceaccount.com`. Same token exception.

So, why are we getting a 403 Access not configured when the Cloudstorage JSON API is clearly enabled under our api/services?

And why is passing a service_account_id to AppAssertionCredentials failing with a AccessTokenRefreshError?

Edit:

**The solution was ridiculous: turn OFF the Google Cloud Storage API, and turn it back ON.**

I assume that the app was a "legacy" app, and doing so made the last bullet point 12 work here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/activate